# Как обратится к тексту на textEdit в qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Мне нужно програмно изменить текст в `QTextEdit`. И не знаю как к нему обратится, точнее к его тексту. Прошу заметить, не `lineEdit`, a `textEdit`(многострочное поле).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    ui->textEdit->setText("ваш текст"); // изменить
    ui->textEdit->toPlainText(); // узнать
```